# Can't update dictionary connected to NSDictionaryController

Tags: swift, xcode, nstableview, cocoa-bindings

I'm playing around with cocoa bindings and table views, and I'm trying to create a simple 2 column table view where the keys are displayed in the left column and values in the right. When I try to add anything to the base dictionary, the build succeeds but I get this:

```
2020-08-10 20:58:36.063356-0400 DictTest[55388:1344906] -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8ff53cf7c2dc61e7
2020-08-10 20:58:36.063531-0400 DictTest[55388:1344906] Failed to set (contentViewController) user defined inspected property on (NSWindow): -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8ff53cf7c2dc61e7
```

As for my bindings (I've done them all through storyboard), I have each column bound to the dictionary controller, controllerKey = arrangedObjects, Model Key Path = key/value depending. For the dictionary controller, I have it bound to the dictionary in my View Controller class, which is as such:

```
@objc dynamic var dict = [Int: String]()
```

I've been trying to add items to it in the conventional way (`dict[0] = "test0"`).

Thanks

Comment: Could you post the project as an example at github?

Comment: Sure, here it is: https://github.com/CamSox1/DictTest

Comment: So you don't see in the console where it says "Failed to connect (dictController) outlet from (DictTest.ViewController) to (NSDictionaryController): missing setter or instance variable"?

Comment: Yeah, that's unrelated. I had connected the controller programmatically to see if I could do something different, but I forget to remove the connection.

Comment: OK just checking we had the same thing....

Comment: I think the key must be a string, see [NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdictionary), "In general, a key can be any object (provided that it conforms to the NSCopying protocol—see below), but note that when using key-value coding the key must be a string".

Comment: Ah, I missed that, that fixes it. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: And in terms of binding the Text Fields and Text Field Cells, the way I normally do it with array controllers seem to crash the program. What should my bindings for each cells be? I've played around with a bunch of different options but they all crash.